# Creating a directory In C or C++

Tags: c++, c

How to create a directory with C code (other than the method of forking and using mkdir) ? Is there anything like dirent.h? dirent.h only allows to read directories. (without using external library)

Comment: I want to know both C and C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [mkdir function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir).

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can use C++ (as suggested by the selected tags) and boost libraries, Boost filesystem can help you with the [create_directory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Operations-functions) function.

If you don't want to have all boost libraries available in your project, you may download a tool called [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html) to extract only the subset you need, in your case boost filesystem and its dependencies.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using boost over mkdir function?

Comment: Boost is pure c++, which means you don't have to convert strings to char*. Boost filesystem lets you use "path" objects which are simple to use if you work with many related directories. There are more reasons to use it, but i haven't dug into it much.

Comment: Boost is also cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

Call [mkdir(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir).

Answer (score 3):

With the advent of `c++17` we have a [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) providing facilities for manipulating files and directory. To create a directory, you can use [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory).

Example:

```
#include <filesystem>
std::filesystem::create_directory("newdir");
```