# How do you create a folder in C++ with no path name just the name of the folder you want to create?

Tags: c++, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a directory In C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256913/creating-a-directory-in-c-or-c)

I want to make a folder that is titled "BobtheBuilder". And then I want to create a text file inside of it. I want to do this without being aware of my path. I don't want to have to type in:

```
ofstream out("C:/MyComputer/User/Jeff/etc/BobtheBuilder/NewFile.txt");
```

I want it just to be local to this area where my executable is contained like this:

```
ofstream out("/BobtheBuilder/NewFile.txt");
```

is this possible? Do I have to know the whole path name in order to do file management? I feel like this is possible because you can create or open a file that is in the same directory as the program like:

```
ifstream inf("NewFile.txt");
```

Or is there a special keyword that fills in the previous path like this:

```
ifstream inf("FILLIN/BobtheBuilder/NewFile.txt");
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the special keyword would be '.' which points to your working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely specify a relative path like *"BobtheBuilder/NewFile.txt"* without specifying the whole path.
You would however need to create the folder first before the file.
Since creating folders is platform specific and since you're on Windows, you would need to call the *CreateDirectory* function with *"BobtheBuilder"* as its parameter.
The folder would then be created in the default working directory of the program which is the same folder where the executable resides.
You can change this working directory using the *SetCurrentDirectory* function before creating the folder and file.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a directory you can use the C function:

```
int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

If you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), then it really becomes easier and more C++ friendly:

```
bool create_directories(const path& p);

// usage example
boost::filesystem::create_directories("./BobtheBuilder");
```

As you mention in your question , you can use both absolute and relative paths. It just depends on what is your intention. In your case, you could just do:

```
boost::filesystem::create_directories("./BobtheBuilder");
ofstream out("./BobtheBuilder/NewFile.txt");
```

not needing to specify the absolute path at all.

If you often need to manage paths, Boost provides many useful tools for path management. Just as an example, consider the problem you mention in your question: you want to get the full path to the current directory and then append a relative path. You could do this very easily:

```
 #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
 namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
 ...
 fs::path curr_abs_path = fs::current_path();
 fs::path rel_path = "foo/bar";
 fs::path combined = (curr_abs_path /= rel_path);
 cout << combined << endl;
```

Assuming the current directory is /tmp/ the previous code snippet would print:

> /tmp/foo/bar

`operator/=` is responsible for appending two paths and returning the combined result.